# sql conflicit with $ in play framework

Tags: postgresql, playframework

I written a sql in my project which is in play!framework ,but the '$' which is the symble of the variable params in sql is confilicted with the '$' in my sql which contails regex. this is the code

```
select substring(cast(id as char(100)),'......$') from users;
```

can anyone help me to deal with this problem,thanks a lot
ps: my DataBase is postgresql

Comment: Please show your PgJDBC version, PostgreSQL version, and the **exact text of the error message or stack trace**. The `$` is in a string literal, which should be just fine unless you've made a mistake elsewhere. If your regexp is really `......$` though, why aren't you just using `right(id, 6)` instead of that mess? Or if you must cast, `right(id::text, 6)` ?

Comment: Also, which database access library are you using?